# Why is my nav bar not aligning to the left?

Tags: html, css

I'm using a site template from w3schools to create a site and I'm having an issue with the Nav bar. There seems to be either margin or padding on the left side of the page that is pushing the Nav Bar right by about 50px and I can't figure out why.

Here's the html/css.

```
<!-- Navbar -->
  <div class="w3-top">
    <div class="w3-bar w3-black w3-card">
      <a class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding-large w3-hide-medium w3-hide-large w3-right" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myFunction()" title="Toggle Navigation Menu"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
      <a href="/" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding-large">HOME</a>
      <a href="#band" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding-large w3-hide-small">BAND</a>
      <a href="#tour" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding-large w3-hide-small">TOUR</a>
      <a href="#contact" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding-large w3-hide-small">CONTACT</a>
        <div class="w3-dropdown-hover w3-hide-small">
        <button class="w3-padding-large w3-button" title="Requests">REQUESTS <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>     
        <div class="w3-dropdown-content w3-bar-block w3-card-4">
          <a href="/requests" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Vote on current Requests</a>
          <a href="/requests/new" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Submit a new Request</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="w3-dropdown-hover w3-hide-small">
        <button class="w3-padding-large w3-button" title="More">MORE <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>     
        <div class="w3-dropdown-content w3-bar-block w3-card-4">
          <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Merchandise</a>
          <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Extras</a>
          <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Media</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding-large">
      <% if current_user %>
    <%= link_to 'Log Out', logout_path, {:class => "linkText"} %>
  <% else %>
    <div>

    <%= link_to 'Sign Up', signup_path, {:class => "linkText"} %></a> or 
    <%= link_to 'Log In', login_path, {:class => "linkText"} %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
      </div>

      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="w3-padding-large w3-hover-red w3-hide-small w3-right"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
    </div>

  </div>
```

The CSS classes are available here: https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_references.asp

I'm slowly starting to build my own classes to replace these, but I can't figure out what's causing the padding to appear.

Comment: Please tell me why this was downvoted

Comment: Not my downvote, but this isn't a minimal, runnable example demonstrating the problem. You've got rails code in there and just a link to the css instead of grabbing the relevant parts and including them here or including a link tag in a snipped that we can test.

Comment: I found out that removing require_tree from the application.css file makes it work. I have no idea why

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a non-answer answer. I put your code in a snippet and included the w3.css and I don't see the issue. Perhaps this helps now that you know that it is actually a problem with something else in your project.

```html
<link href="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="w3-top">
    <div class="w3-bar w3-black w3-card">
      <a class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding-large w3-hide-medium w3-hide-large w3-right" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myFunction()" title="Toggle Navigation Menu"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
      <a href="/" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding-large">HOME</a>
      <a href="#band" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding-large w3-hide-small">BAND</a>
      <a href="#tour" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding-large w3-hide-small">TOUR</a>
      <a href="#contact" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding-large w3-hide-small">CONTACT</a>
        <div class="w3-dropdown-hover w3-hide-small">
        <button class="w3-padding-large w3-button" title="Requests">REQUESTS <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>     
        <div class="w3-dropdown-content w3-bar-block w3-card-4">
          <a href="/requests" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Vote on current Requests</a>
          <a href="/requests/new" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Submit a new Request</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="w3-dropdown-hover w3-hide-small">
        <button class="w3-padding-large w3-button" title="More">MORE <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>     
        <div class="w3-dropdown-content w3-bar-block w3-card-4">
          <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Merchandise</a>
          <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Extras</a>
          <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Media</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding-large">
        Button here...
      </div>

      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="w3-padding-large w3-hover-red w3-hide-small w3-right"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
    </div>

  </div>
```